# SNI and TLS errors on apache reverse proxy host when proxying multiple sites from different servers?

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, sni

I have an apache2 reverse proxy which is proxying many services including zabbix and nextcloud, and applying a wildcard SSL certificate to said services.  These are individual virtual hosts, though they all use the same CA-verified wildcard SSL cert.  This is, in principle, working perfectly.  The zabbix server and nextcloud servers are their own VM's, and if I load up "https://zabbix.domain.tld" OR "https://nextcloud.domain.tld" in firefox, everything is wonderful and I have no errors in the server logs.

However, if I load up firefox and open 2 tabs, one with "https://nextcloud.domain.tld" and one with "https://zabbix.domain.tld" my apache logs start showing the following errors:

```
[Tue Jul 18 14:15:31.891105 2023] [ssl:error] [pid 357025:tid 140406695503424] [client 10.#.#.#:59958] AH02032: Hostname nextcloud.domain.tld provided via SNI and hostname zabbix.domain.tld provided via HTTP have no compatible SSL setup
[Tue Jul 18 14:15:38.849413 2023] [ssl:error] [pid 357022:tid 140406779430464] [client 10.#.#.#:59962] AH02032: Hostname zabbix.domain.tld provided via SNI and hostname nextcloud.domain.tld provided via HTTP have no compatible SSL setup
```

In general, everything is working, but these are 2 sites I often leave up so my logs are getting spammed.  Is this something I should worry about?  I have not been able to find any counter-indications with my apache config.  I have been worried that somehow the hostname of the reverse proxy is bleeding through but nothing I have been able to debug with online TLS checkers or various curl commands show anything?

Below is the zabbix config, which is ultimately the same thing as the nextcloud one:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName zabbix.domain.tld
        ServerAlias zabbix.domain.tld
        ServerAlias *.zabbix.domain.tld
        RequestHeader set X-SCHEME https
        ProxyPass / https://10.2.2.202/
        ProxyPassReverse / https://10.2.2.202/
#        RewriteEngine on
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.zabbix.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.zabbix.log combined
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/wildcard.domain.tld.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/wildcard.domain.tld.key
        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/RapidSSL.Intermediate.crt
        SSLHonorCipherOrder On
        SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
        SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDS
A-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA25
6:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK
        SSLInsecureRenegotiation off
        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
        # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
        SSLProxyEngine          On
        ProxyRequests           On
        SSLProxyVerify          none 
        SSLProxyCheckPeerCN     off
        SSLProxyCheckPeerName   off
        SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
        ProxyPreserveHost       On
        RequestHeader           set             X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
</VirtualHost>
```